# Converting Cuda Array1 of Typename1 to Array2 of Typename2

Tags: memory-management, cuda

Dear Cuda Scholars,
 Looking for solution for the below problem

a) I have two arrays 
 1) array1 of size1 which is of typename1
 2) array2 of size1 which is of typename2

b) I am wanting to write a kernel of the following prototype

`__global__ kernel(void* dest, void* src, int dest_sizeoftype, int src_sizeoftype, int num_array_elts);`

c) Supposing I create num_array_elts cuda threads, each threads copying its elt to from src to destination.

Issue:
a) The place I am getting stuck is which function to use to copy num_bytes from src to dest in the kernel.

Thanking you in advance
Regards,
Nagaraju

Answer (score 2):

The `copy` algorithm in [Thrust](http://code.google.com/p/thrust/) makes this easy.

```
#include <thrust/copy.h>
#include <thrust/device_ptr.h>

int   * src = ...
float * dst = ...

// first wrap the 'raw' pointers
thrust::device_ptr<int>   wrapped_src(src);
thrust::device_ptr<float> wrapped_dst(dst);

// then pass wrapped pointers to copy()
thrust::copy(wrapped_src, wrapped_src + num_array_elts, wrapped_dst);
```

Refer to the [QuickStart](http://code.google.com/p/thrust/wiki/QuickStartGuide) guide for additional info about Thrust.

Comment: Sometimes cuda does not support double, can I used it for double also ? If src is double and dst is short is the scenario ... Thank you.

Comment: The code above will work for doubles if the CUDA device supports them.  In principle you could convert doubles to shorts on earlier devices (Compute Capability 1.0 and 1.1), but it would be difficult and time-consuming.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the types of the 2 arrays this problem becomes fairly trivial.

```
__global__ kernel(float* dest, int* src){

    int idx=blockIdx.x*blockDim.x+threadIdx.x;
    dest[ idx ] = src[ idx ];

}
```

If your dest array used a larger word e.g. a double, this would still work and there would be no need to know the number of bytes. Just make sure you allocate the correct number of bytes when using [cudamalloc](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/2_3/toolkit/docs/online/group__CUDART__MEMORY_gc63ffd93e344b939d6399199d8b12fef.html).